# How can I filter a set of data based on a column containing a given date in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a set of data in sheets, and the first column is an automated date added record. I would then like to filter this data set on a number of criteria including whether the date added matches a date input into a certain cell, in this case A2.

The date added record is in the format `10/03/2016 19:25:45`.

The filter I am currently trying to use is

```
=FILTER(
  'Output Checker'!A:P,
  'Output Checker'!A:A=contains(A2),
  'Output Checker'!L:L <2, 
  'Output Checker'!M:M ="NO",
  'Output Checker'!N:N ="Yes", 
  'Output Checker'!O:O ="NO"
)
```

where A2 = `10/03/2016`

but this keeps throwing up a

> N/A No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Try

```
=FILTER(
  'Output Checker'!A:P,
  ROUNDDOWN('Output Checker'!A:A)=A2,
  'Output Checker'!L:L <2, 
  'Output Checker'!M:M ="NO",
  'Output Checker'!N:N ="Yes", 
  'Output Checker'!O:O ="NO"
)
```

## Explanation

Google Sheets doesn't have a built-in function called CONTAINS. 
To evaluate that a date-time value met a date only criteria, round down the date value. This works because Google Sheets uses serialized numbers for date-times where, days are whole numbers and hours are fractions of a day (1 hour = 1 / 24 of a day).

Comment: The way that thanks is said in this site is upvoting a helpful questions and answers, by the other side as the author of a question you could mark an answer as accepted. For further details, please take a look to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)